# How to search through nested values of attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

Hi I have a sample app which has 3 objects in seed file:

```
students =[{
  name: "John",
  hobby: "sport"},
{
  name: "Bill",
  hobby: "science"},
{
  name: "Evit Tom",
  hobby: ["sport","science"]}]

students.each do |student|
  School.create(student)
end
```

I search them with check boxes form:

```
<%= form_tag student_list_path %>
  Hobby:
  <ul>
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'hobby[]', "Sport" %> Sport</li> 
    <li><%= check_box_tag 'hobby[]', "Science" %> Science</li>     
  </ul>            
<%= submit_tag "Show" %>
```

And in controller I have:

```
@hobby = params[:hobby]
@schools = Student.student_search(@hobby).to_a
```

And in my Student model:

```
     def self.student_search(hobby)
       School.where(hobby: hobby)
     end
```

My trouble is to get the Evil Tom object. I know that this is becouse of the array value of this object hobby attribute. But I don`t know how to get to it.

I tried to make a 'search_array' method in my Studen model.

```
   def array_search(array)
     temp = []
     array.each do |value|
       case value
       when Array
         array_search(value)
       else
         temp << value
       end
       temp
     end
   end
```

And use it in a search action like this:

```
     def self.student_search(hobby)
       hobby_s = array_search(hobby)
       School.where(hobby: hobby_s)
     end
```

But I get undefinded method, I don`t know why since it is defined in Student class.

My main problem is how to get the 'Evil Tom' object if you have any ideas pleas post :) I will get code by my self. I need just the hint.

Comment: I am sorry but I have to ask this `students.each do |school|` do you really mean to create `school` for each student ? Also the variable naming looks very wrong. I think your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: It suppose to be `students.each do |student|` The problem is I don`t really know how to be more specyfic. The question is supposted to be "How to get sql where search get through array value of attribute" or something like this. Mayby you know how to ask this question more specyfic ?

Comment: You should not have to write `array_search` method by yourself, this is where you can use `active_record`. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve given you have `Student`, `School` as model and `hobby` as `student` attribute ?